# Selenium - Wait for the ScrollIntoView to finish

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I need to scroll to an element and take a screenshot of the page but the driver takes the screenshot before the page is completely scrolled to the element. I've used a time sleep in this way

```
driver.execute_script("""arguments[0].scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'nearest', inline: 'start' });""", element)
time.sleep(1)
scr = driver.get_screenshot_as_png()
```

but I really don't want to use sleeps since they are not test-oriented. I've tried to wait for the element to be visible but it didn't work too. Another attempt was to move to the element with ActionChains but it doesn't show the entire element moving on it. Is there a way to wait for the scroll to finish? Besides this specific case of the screenshot, it would be useful knowing a way to wait for the scroll to finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using Javascript waiting until the element is fully visible:

```
def wait_until_specific_condition(func, timeout=30):
  
    endtime = time.time() + timeout
    while True:
       if time.time() > endtime:
            raise TimeoutException("The condition is not satisfied")
       result = func()
       if result is True:
            return result
```

So with this function I wait until a specific condition is satisfied; in my case the condition is the entire visibility of the element obtained using Javascript in this way:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'nearest', inline: 'start' });",
                          element)
is_visible_script = """function isScrolledIntoView(el) {
                                    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
                                    var elemTop = rect.top;
                                    var elemBottom = rect.bottom;
                                
                                    // Only completely visible elements return true:
                                    var isVisible = (elemTop >= 0) && (elemBottom <= window.innerHeight);
                                    // Partially visible elements return true:
                                    //isVisible = elemTop < window.innerHeight && elemBottom >= 0;
                                    return isVisible;
                                }
                           return isScrolledIntoView(arguments[0]);"""
wait_until_specific_condition(lambda: driver.execute_script(is_visible_script, element))
```

Comment: Does this still work?

Comment: yes, it is still working for me

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void fullScren(String filename) throws IOException
{

        Screenshot myScreenshot = new AShot().shootingStrategy(ShootingStrategies.viewportPasting(100)).takeScreenshot(driver);
        ImageIO.write(myScreenshot.getImage(),"PNG",new File("src/main/java/ScreenShots/" + filename + ".jpg"));
    }
```

You have to use this scroll down and take full screen shot by selenium

Comment: Ashot is Used for that

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"yourelementslocator")))
```

use visibility of Expected condition

Comment: this doesn't work because the visibility is satisfied even if the element is not entirely visible

Comment: Execute script is synchronous it should return only after acton completes what issue are you facing without the wait

Comment: After adding time.sleep you are getting correct screen shot ?

Comment: What happenes if you remove the properties and just use scrollintoview()

Comment: After time.sleep i get the correct screenshot and if I remove the properties it scrolls to the element but It doesn't show the element entirely since it is a quite big element

Comment: you have any demo website to try this on

Comment: I can't post it here